# Is there a paradox in the field of immunology for the elderly patients?

Tags: immunology

Say you have an 80 year-old. You can spray anti-bacterial in their door knobs, keys, floors, walls, bathroom. So now less-bacteria. But by doing that, you weaken their immune system, so if they're back in a higher-density bacteria environment, they are now weaker then if you didn't put them in the sterile environment?

Obviously, this paradox does not apply to toddlers, which is the best time to expose someone to bacteria/viruses.

Comment: You do not weaken the immune system by removing bacteria. Additionally, with the methods available at home, you will not be able to kill all bacteria. So this is nonsense.

Comment: @Chris it's like that for me with allergies. If I'm not exposed to cats for a while, I get re-allergic to cars. If I don't eat ice cream for a year, I end up gassing a lot when I have ice cream for the 1st time. If I don't read while in motion, I'll eventually get motion sickness from reading again.

Isn't our body constantly fighting decomposition, so constantly fighting bacteria from taking over our body? So what do you think happens when our body is put in a sterile environment, and then put back in the previous environment?

Comment: @NealConroy nothing, your examples are allergic (aka abnormal ) reactions and lactose breakdown which has nothing to do with the immune system.  one way to treat allergic reactions is controlled exposure thus reducing the immune system response, if we went by that example it should make the immune system stronger. But neither is good model for how the normal immune system works.

Comment: @John well why is it when we die, the bacteria take over and eat our flesh? Because we are no longer fighting it. So basically, when we are alive our body is constantly fighting against decay.

Answer (score 4):

To borrow a phrase that was widely heard during the last three years: "Immunology is complicated". You seem to be assuming it functions similarly to a muscle that atrophies with disuse. This is far too simplistic.

For example, I was immunized against smallpox when I was three or so. I've never been exposed to smallpox and I'm in my sixties now, but the odds are that I retain strong immunity to smallpox. To highlight just one of the immune subsystems, there is a class of immune cells called [Memory B cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_B_cell#:%7E:text=B%20lymphocytes%20are%20the%20cells,antibody%20production%20in%20future%20infections.). Their job is to "record" chemical signals from pathogens you have encountered, either from infection or vaccination. These cells then hang out in your blood for decades. If the Memory B cells encounter that pathogen again, they activate and interact with other parts of the immune system and vastly accelerate an immune response to kill off the pathogen.

Notice that I said "odds". There are many probabilistic aspects to the immune system. When you get vaccinated or sick with an infection, you will generate millions of Memory B cells targeted at that infection. As I said, these cells can remain dormant in your blood stream for decades. As you age, some of them will die off, and if you are unlucky, enough of them may die off that they may not be able to respond effectively to their target pathogen. The gradual dying off of Memory B cells, is just one aspect of the [overall decline of the immune system with age](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5291468/#:%7E:text=Beginning%20with%20the%20sixth%20decade,to%20support%20appropriate%20wound%20healing.). In other situations older folks may still have well functioning Memory B cells, but the [other systems that do the actual killing may have become weakened and ineffective](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1782064/#:%7E:text=Thus%2C%20aging%20is%20associated%20with,and%20natural%20killer%2FT%20cells.). This is the motivation for being particularly careful with sanitation around the elderly: they may no longer be able to mount a strong immune response even to pathogens they've seen and fought off many times before.

> If I'm not exposed to cats for a while, I get re-allergic to cars. If
> I don't eat ice cream for a year, I end up gassing a lot when I have
> ice cream for the 1st time.

Your experience may very well be an example of the ability of the immune system to form long-lasting "memories". Note that it isn't the cat hair or the ice cream itself that causes the unpleasant symptoms, it's your immune system's response to them that causes the problems. At some point you were exposed to cat hair and your immune system erroneously decided it was pathogenic, and "memorized" how to recognize it so it could mount a response the next time it encountered it. However, it seems that continued exposure to small doses of an antigen can eventually convince the immune system (at least temporarily) that the substance is OK and doesn't require an immune response. Exactly how this happens [is not well understood](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3233381/). This isn't a case of the immune system "forgetting" how to deal with a threat, it's more like it remembering all too well its first impression.

An excellent popular book on the immune system and its complexities is "[An Elegant Defense](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/41806641-an-elegant-defense)".

Comment: Charles, 1st off I thought allergies, and bodies immune system to bacteria and viruses, are separate? My allergies to cats is just red eyes and blowing nose. So, yes, I asked an immunology professor, your environment changes, your allergy-immune system changes. Somehow, bacteria and virus immune system retains a lot longer.

Comment: Like I said, "Immunology is complicated". Allergies and responses to pathogens differ, but do involve shared subsystems of the overall immune system. The "memory" for [allergens also involves Memory B cells, but usually of a different subtype, than handles pathogens](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41577-023-00870-0#:~:text=Allergies%20can%20be%20lifelong%2C%20but,phenotype%20is%20not%20well%20described.).

Comment: Charles, but the part that is much more complicated in immunology is allergies, as opposed to bacteria and viruses. Immune system to bacteria is pretty straightforward, immunity to viruses is rather moot, as viruses change over time. It'd be interesting to see what kinds of things our immunity loses quickest to least. Could very well be motion sickness.

Comment: "Immune system to bacteria is pretty straightforward" need citation! Here is a research project for you: tell me how many classes of cells are involved in the human immune response to a bacterial infection. "immunity to viruses is rather moot, as viruses change over time": some do, some don't, as is also the case with bacteria (that's why we're having to deal with anti-biotic resistant strains of bacteria now). "Could very well be motion sickness." OK, you've lost me now. Motion sickness doesn't having anything to do with the immune system (cont)

Comment: Charles, I was allergic to acts, at age 12, got my1st kitten, was allergic to it for a day and a half. Then slept with the cat for 6 years, then moved out for college at age 18, at age 19, came back to mom's house and allergies to cat all over, and this time, it took weeks to get over. But lose it within a year. Same thing with motion sickess. 1 time, I read something so interesting while in a bus, that when I got off the bus, I had to throw up. But the next day, I was able to read while on bus/train no problem, so played video games. But within a year, had to start all over... Viruses seem to

Comment: Viruses seem to change 50% in about 4 years, so it seems to be much easier to keep track of bacterial immunity. But I don't know a good example of it. As winter colds are caused by viruses. By the way, regarding motion sickness, I constantly threw up in the car at age 4 over long-distance highways, so got immune to that quick. I have a feeling, if I went to jail for a year, and come out, rode a public bus, I'd feel dizzy. But I ride the bus every day. If I don't ride the playground swings for a while, it feels a little dizzy too.

Comment: [Motion sickness is caused by a conflict between neural input from the vestibular system and your visual system](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4112051/). It is sometimes treated with anti-histamines, but that's simply to suppress your impulse to vomit.

Comment: With respect Neal, you're telling your self 'just-so' stories linking your issues, and you are fixating on things like "Viruses seem to change 50% in about 4 years" that simply aren't true. Rather than spin your stories explaining a sample set of 1, I urge you to do some reading on the subject.

Comment: Charles, viruses specifically for rotavirus and norovirus, that cause gastroenteritis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147535/discussion-between-charles-e-grant-and-neal-conroy).

Comment: I seem to have lost my ability to post in the chat, here's my reply: Charles I didn't change my point. The sickness from sewers was the 2 viruses. And after 4 years, I got sick again at some 50% intensity, hence my logic. I realize now the microbio professor is not the immunology professor. Though the immunology professor should know more about microbio than the microbio professor knows about immunology, so I know now to ask the immunology professor. Which I lost touch of. But they did back my allegation on cats, that my allergies to cats was lost after losing exposure for over a year.

Comment: I also seem to have problems tagging people @Charles E. Grant